# How to increment output file with ID number from table (javascript)

Tags: javascript

For each new transaction, a new id number (transaction_id) is entered in the transaction table. Is there a way to read that number and add it to the output file.

var file_name = "output."+"transaction_id";

Eg transaction number 1, output file output.1.txt, transaction number 2, output file output.2.txt, etc ...

Thanks to all of you.

When I create a new transaction in the program, the program automatically gives the transaction number (autonumber), for example. 10 in the transaction table. When I print this transaction, I get the name of the output file output.txt. I would like my output file to be called output.10.txt. Also for new transaction 11 that my output file is called output.11.txt, and so on. Can this ID number be taken from the transaction table and added to the output file name?

The solution is simple, just call the id from the database. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. Where is the table? can you show us the table. Is the problem in retrieving the last transaction_id or in constructing the file name?. Show us the code you have wrote and were you are getting mixed up

Comment: is that screenshot a web browser showing a web page? you used the tag javascript but there's nothing clear about the context. To fetch those values it must be clear the whole scenario. Is that a web page? do you want to run your code in that page? You say it's a program saving files when you print a transaction? too much confusion

Comment: is the text from the table coming from a database, is it written in the html as text or  user can add it from an input?